# Why nginx serves a custom named .ico but not favicon.ico?

Tags: nginx

My Nginx server responds with `404` when client requests for a `/favicon.ico`, but all works well if I rename the thing anything else, e.g. `wip-icon.ico`. Why?

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index   index.html;
  }
}
```

The served page (where I changed `"/favicon.ico"` to `"/wip-icon.ico"`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/wip-icon.ico" />
    <title>Work in progress</title>
  </head>
  <body id="root">
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Host (where I previously had `favicon.ico` instead of `wip-icon.ico`):

```
root@container:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
50x.html  bundle.js  bundle.js.LICENSE.txt  index.html  wip-icon.ico
```

The issue is reproducible using the official Nginx Docker image using the following bash script:

```sh
function runInNewContainer {
  mkdir -p favicon-issue/www
  cd favicon-issue/www
  echo "<!doctype html><head><meta charset=utf-8><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"/$1\" /></head>" > index.html
  touch $1
  echo $'FROM nginx\nCOPY . /usr/share/nginx/html' > Dockerfile
  docker build --tag $1 .
  docker run --name $1 -d -p $2:80 $1
  echo "Listening at port $2!"
  rm $1
  cd ../..
}
runInNewContainer 'favicon.ico' 8888
runInNewContainer 'custom.ico' 8889
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caching. Using `curl -I <host>:<port>/favicon.ico` responded with `200 OK` because curl doesn't cache.